# Choosing partners based on preferences algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I need to assign people to groups based on the preferences they set for each other.

a’s preferences: b, d, c
b’s preferences: a, c, d
c’s preferences: a, b, d
d’s preferences: a, b, c

The correct answer would be {a, b} and {c, d}
How would the algorithm to do this work?
Would I assign values to each person's preference?

Comment: In your sample data, each of the lettered people has a preference for the other three people in the group.  So why couldn't `{a, c}` and `{b, d}` be a possible match?

Comment: Hi Tim! It could be. But I have been asked to prove how {a, b} and {c, d} are the best possible matches

Comment: Are the lists sorted by order of preference?

Comment: I assume so. That would explain why {a, b} and {c, d} are the best possible matches?

Comment: I don't understand the problem completely, because I don't know how to quantitatively interpret those list of people.  Please add more detail.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_roommates_problem is what you need to look into

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I was looking for SaiBot! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could assign a,b, to be male; c,d to be female and solve it as an instance of the [Stable marriage problem](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem) and use the Gale-Shapley algorithm mentioned to solve it.

Comment: I've used Irving's algorithm and the Stable Roommates Problem to solve this. This way I don't need to assign to male or female :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider a greedy solution, read about activity selection to get an idea about the greedy solution
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_selection_problem